# How to remove value of magento 2 custom attribute through csv

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom product attribute named 'product_custom_label' on **Magento ver. 2.1** which I been showing on product listing page. For updating its values I have provided the client with the CSV upload sheet like so:

```
sku | product_custom_label
d-12  new arrival
d-13  discounted
```

Updating the values is fine , but what I faced a problem is when I have to empty these values .

If I just remove the values from product_custom_label in the CSV, the attribute values are not emptied. I have already prepared a script to remove these values programatically but I wonder is not there a Magento way to remove/empty the values that we upload through csv?

The same problem is faced when I update the special price of the product.

So, is there any Magento way to empty out the value from a specific custom product attribute, or we just have to rely on mass edit functionality?

Comment: which magento2 version you are using?

Comment: as specifed in the question i am using magento 2.1

Comment: In magento 2.1 this is empty functionality not available by default.

Comment: @RakeshVarma , so what should be informed to client in such case , the mass edit option ?

Comment: Yes, that is the only option as now.

Answer (score 2):

**Only Available in 2.3.x**

You can unset the value of an attribute by passing `__EMPTY__VALUE__` in your column name.
You can change the value define in **Empty attribute value constant**

See the screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: i do not see any option like this in our magento setup , it must be something new introduced in latest version , i have checked in magento 2.1 and magento 2.2 .

Comment: Very very helpful. Thank you friend!